# Not getting a specified data from get request in json server when i use something else rather than id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, json-server

i want to get a specific user from json-server with his email here's my json file

```
{
"Person":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"Bahy",
            "email":"bahy@gmail.com",
            "password":"kkk",
            "phone":"0221223213",
            "gender":"M",
            "dateOfBirth":"4/11/1999",
            "type":"A",
            "carddata":{"cardNumber":"anything","cardexpiary":"anything","cvv":"anything"}
        },
}
```

and here's my function

```
getPerson(email: string): Observable<IPerson> {
    return this.http.get<IPerson>(`${environment.ApiRootLink}/Person?email=${email}`);
  }
```

and here's the usage of this function

```
user:IPerson;
getPerson(email?email:"").subscribe((data)=>{
      this.user=data as IPerson;
      console.log(this.user);
    });
```

so this function intead of giving me the object it gives me this output

[image]

so does anyone know what kind of problem here bec when i try the same http on postman it works fine